# No permission to access my usb device, which is in /dev/ttyUSB0, even though I am in dialout

Tags: usb, permissions

Ubuntu 14.04 problem: It seems I do not have permission to access ttyUSB0, though
**I am already in the dialout group.(and logged out and back in)**

```
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ chmod 666 ttyUSB0 
chmod: changing permissions of 'ttyUSB0': Operation not permitted
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ groups
compsci adm dialout sudo video groups: cannot find name for group ID 1096176595
109617659
```

even after I change the permissions using `sudo` I still cannot access it from my account.

```
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ sudo chmod 666 ttyUSB0 
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ ls -l ttyUSB0 
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 May 15 16:15 ttyUSB0
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ chmod 666 ttyUSB0
chmod: changing permissions of 'ttyUSB0': Operation not permitted
```

The bigger problem:

I am trying to run some Aria code that communicates with a robot via USB. I have run it before and everything worked fine. For some reason it does not work anymore. Running the program with sudo or not does not help. The program tries to access the robot through ttyS0, but I created a symbolic link from ttyUSB0 to ttyS0.

Also I have tried to run the Aria code through ROS, which tries to connect through ttyUSB0, and it still does not connect.

**There are different outputs in my code if i have the usb device connected or not, so I think it can detect the device, but maybe does not have permission to read/write**

Device Connected:

```
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ rosrun rosaria RosAria
[ INFO] [1431722006.042624050]: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Trying to close possible old connection
Syncing 0
No packet.
Syncing 0
No packet.
 Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
No packet.
 Robot may be connected but not open, trying to dislodge.
Syncing 0
No packet.
Could not connect, no robot responding.
Failed to connect to robot.
[ERROR] [1431722012.788049009]: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot! (Check ~port parameter is correct, and permissions on port device.)
[FATAL] [1431722012.788127232]: RosAria: ROS node setup failed..
```

Device NOT connected:

```
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ rosrun rosaria RosAria
[ INFO] [1431722075.336807723]: RosAria: using port: [/dev/ttyUSB0]
Could not connect to simulator, connecting to robot through serial port /dev/ttyUSB0.
ArSerialConnection::open: Could not open serial port '/dev/ttyUSB0' | ErrorFromOSNum: 2 ErrorFromOSString: No such file or directory
Could not connect, because open on the device connection failed.
Failed to connect to robot.
[ERROR] [1431722075.385556969]: RosAria: ARIA could not connect to robot! (Check ~port parameter is correct, and permissions on port device.)
[FATAL] [1431722075.385627788]: RosAria: ROS node setup failed...
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04

```
ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ stat /dev/ttyUSB0
  File: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 5h/5d   Inode: 290088      Links: 1     Device type: bc,0
Access: (0660/crw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   20/ dialout)
Access: 2015-05-15 21:52:26.118904498 -0400
Modify: 2015-05-15 21:52:26.118904498 -0400
Change: 2015-05-15 21:52:26.118904498 -0400
 Birth: -
```

Comment: Have you tried running the program as root (though generally THIS IS A REALLY BAD IDEA), and what is the output of `id`?

Answer (score 1):

It's expected that you cannot change this file's permissions as a regular user because you're not this device's owner. Nothing out of the ordinary here.

With regards to symlinking the /dev/ttyUSB0 as /dev/ttyS0 - I think it's a bad idea. Unless you have a source of the program trying to use the port, you don't really know how the developer checks for the device node of the serial port. Maybe it checks the device is a character device (symlink doesn't satisfy this condition) and then fails?

I'd always prefer using the program command line flag to specify a port over making workaround such as symlinking.

```
ArSerialConnection::open: Could not open serial port '/dev/ttyUSB0' | ErrorFromOSNum: 2 ErrorFromOSString: No such file or directory
Could not connect, because open on the device connection failed.
```

What's the output of `stat /dev/ttyUSB0` when you run this command?

Also - after adding your regular user account to the `dialout` group, did you log out and then back in?

Comment: `ammirato@bvision4:/dev$ stat /dev/ttyUSB0
  File: '/dev/ttyUSB0'
  Size: 0          Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   character special file
Device: 5h/5d Inode: 158529      Links: 1     Device type: bc,0
Access: (0660/crw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (   20/ dialout)
Access: 2015-05-15 19:52:50.268889238 -0400
Modify: 2015-05-15 19:52:50.268889238 -0400
Change: 2015-05-15 19:52:50.268889238 -0400
 Birth: -
`

I logged out and back in many times :)

Comment: Could you update your answer with this output so that formatting is preserved?

Answer (score 1):

Given your permissions are correct:

```
$ ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Okt 28 04:09 /dev/ttyUSB0
$ id
uid=1000(you) ... 20(dialout)
```

It seems there is a problem with the software. I had exactly the same problem today. The following command revealed that the problem was somewhere else:

```
strace -ff igotugui >strace.txt 2>&1
```

Then, in the strace.txt I found lines like (for all existing devices by the way):

```
[pid 13391] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb/004/001", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 13391] ioctl(28, USBDEVFS_CONNECTINFO, 0x7f4efa5c6a58) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
[pid 13391] openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/bus/usb/003/010", O_RDWR) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
[pid 13391] ioctl(28, USBDEVFS_CONNECTINFO, 0x7f4efa5c6a58) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

For now, I don't know how to find out which is the relevant device name (it's a different one every time you connect the device physically), but for your program to work, you have to change the permissions of that device file:

```
sudo chgrp dialout /dev/bus/usb/003/010
```

**Update**

Today I know more. You can use lsusb for getting the device id:

```
$ lsusb
[...]
Bus 003 Device 010: ID dead:beef Your awesome device
```

So, take Bus as the first path part, and Device as the second one.

Or, you can write an udev rule for it:

```
# /etc/udev/rules.d/51-awesomedevice.rules:
SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="dead", ATTRS{idProduct}=="beef", GROUP="dialout", MODE="0660"
```